# MYSQL pick up where I left off in case of page failure

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm writing users to a database and I want to be able to start "were I left off" if the page timesout.

my current code is here

```
 $sql = "SELECT * 
            FROM  `user` 
            WHERE  `setting` LIKE CONVERT( _utf8 '1 %'
            USING latin1 ) 
            COLLATE latin1_swedish_ci";


     while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {

        //add a user to seperate database


}
```

As you can see pretty simple, but if the page fails I have no way of knowing where I was, and it will add users twice. Any ideas what to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although this can be taken care by creating a `UNIQUE INDEX` on the field which should be unique (user id).

But in this case, still process will be repeated from the **first** record.

So, we should better handle it in your `$sql` like following:

```
 $sql = "SELECT * 
            FROM  `db1.user` 
            WHERE  `setting` LIKE CONVERT( _utf8 '1 %'
            USING latin1 ) and userid NOT in (Select userid from `db2.user`)
            COLLATE latin1_swedish_ci";
```

Comment: would it be possible to add another term to narrow down the results further. Because they might already be in this table just with a different value for one of the columns. So if they're not in there AND they do not have a entry equal to a value

Comment: yes, you can add where clause to that as well. `userid NOT in (Select u2.userid from db2.user u2 where <condition>)`

Answer (score 2):

The best way to do this would be to use IF NOT EXISTS clause . First check whether the user exists in the new database by it's email-id or any other unique key . Then insert the user if it does not exist .

Comment: Would it be possible to do IF NOT EXISTS on two of the tables: for example username and email

Comment: tables or fields ? if username and email are two fields of the table in which you are inserting the user then you can use something like :- INSERT INTO user_table (field1,field2,field3) VALUES (value1,value2,value3) IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM user_table WHERE username=somevalue AND email=someothervalue)

Answer (score 0):

If you will use the `INSERT` statement for adding new users and will have the appropriate indexes in place, then this itself should be enough to make sure the user will not get add twice in the database.

More information:

- MySQL Reference Manual: [INSERT Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can (and probably should) [isolate your script using transactions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/commit.html) in conjunction with a [unique index](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/constraint-primary-key.html). If you structure your transactions correctly, you'll know **precisely** where you were.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to others, alternatively create a boolean column in the `user` table and have the default value to be 0. In your loop block update the user row to 1. That way you'll know where you left off. And add a `AND` clause to your SQL statement like this

```
$sql = "SELECT * 
        FROM  `user` 
        WHERE  `setting` LIKE CONVERT( _utf8 '1 %'
        USING latin1 ) 
        AND `carried`= 0
        COLLATE latin1_swedish_ci";


 while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {

    //add a user to seperate database

    mysql_query(UPDATE `user` SET `carried`=1 WHERE `id` = $row['id'])
```

}

When you're done you can delete the `carried` column.